# Calculate distance between slits in diffraction grating?

Tags: diffraction, wavelength

I have a diffraction grating of $1,000$ lines $/$ $mm$, I am using a laser pointer of wavelength $\lambda$ $650$ to $670$ $nm$, (a red colour, which is observed).

When I do the calculation using $1 / 1000 / 1000$ to get the distance $d =1 \times 10^{-6} \;m$, I obtain a wavelength of $592 \pm 30 \;nm$. Now I realize I am not using $d$, but $d$ plus the slit size (assuming an even division of slits and spacing's. If it is edge to edge slits, then the number of spaces = number of slits - 1).

So to get $d$ I should subtract the slit size, which is unknown, but should be the approximate size of the wavelength. If I remove $670 \;nm$ from $d$. I get a wavelength of $195 \; nm$. Which is "less" correct than when I just use $d = 1 \times 10^{-6} \;m$. Because, I am getting much smaller size I should add on some distance?

Is there a way to get a more accurate calculation of the distance $d$ between two slits in my diffraction grating?

Comment: The “d” is the distance from the centre of one slit to the centre of the adjacent slit.

Comment: @Farcher, right I forgot that, I was calculating based on the edges of the spacing. So I should use 1/999/1000 for my d value. (lines - 1 = 999).

Comment: Using 1000 is fine. I do not know what apparatus you have access to but you might try and find the wavelength by another method eg using a steel rule. http://kamaljeeth.net/newsite/index.php?route=product/product/getProductAttachmentFile&attachment_id=292 PS I have found that laser pointer sometimes change in wavelength during an experiment possibly due to battery drain.

Comment: What things did you measure to do this? I would assume you have distance from grating to pattern and possibly measured from central maximum to one of the next maxima? Interestingly my students do a related experiment, though when i did it i got very close using the manufacturers stated value of d.

Comment: @Farcher But why we need just to take the inverse to find the distance between two slits?